# Set new contentURL for MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app a video is played via a MPMoviePlayerController. However it can happen that the currently played video should be replaced with a new one by setting a new contentURL.

If I do this, the current video stops and the movie player turns black. But the new video wont load. It just turns black without displaying any controls.

The moviePlayer's loadState then stays `MPMovieLoadStateUnknown`. I am 100% sure that the contentURL is valid, I also tried to re-set the exact same url to make sure.

I also tried `[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay]` after re-setting the contentURL, but that doesn't change anything.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: I know that it is stupid but u r using <code>[moviePlayer play];</code> after setting the new url?

Answer (score 5):

Set the `movieSourceType` again, right before you set the new `contentURL` value.

```
self.player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
self.player.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
```